How Do I Achieve This Interface In Flutter
I am trying to have a small section of the body of the App use a background colour having the same colour with the Appbar so that it looks like the UI on the attached image.


You can achieve with Stack widget, you need Container, and wrap Container with Positioned widget to position your container

It would be also nice to provide a simple coding example.

You can use Stack like this:
          Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: 0,
                right: 0,
                left: 0,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 200,
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 100,
                right: 20,
                left: 20,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: const Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(0.11),
                        spreadRadius: 0,
                        blurRadius: 16,
                        offset: const Offset(0, 2),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 12, 16, 12),
                  height: 200,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text('title'),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Text('content1'),
                          Text('content2'),
                          Text('content3'),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )


What about the Appear, won't the Appbar have same colour with the stacked widget?
